# Turn off mirror display on startup on Elementary OS

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr, elementary-os, multi-monitor

I'm running Elementary OS Freya Beta 2 with dual displays. I added some xrandr commands to run at startup so the monitor I want is the primary monitor and that the dock starts on the right monitor. Now whenever I restart the machine, the display mirrors. Is there a way to force the display not to mirror?

I can go into Settings>Display and turn off "mirror display" but I don't want to do that every time I restart. Where I can I permanently modify those settings?

Here are the things I've tried:

- `xrandr`: There's nothing I can see in there that forces not mirrored displays
- `xorg.conf`: As far as I can tell I don't have an xorg.conf file and cannot automatically generate one. If the answer is to create one from scratch I can do that. I just don't know what to put in it.
- drivers: I tried using the proprietary ATI drivers but that cause a lot of graphical issues, right now I'm just working with the xorg drivers

Comment: I also don't have a ~/.config/monitors.xml file. If I need to create that and add specific settings. I can do that as well. I'm not sure specifically what I would add though.

Comment: Can you tell us what the xrandr command is that you are adding to startup?  does it include positioning information?

Comment: I have a left and right monitor. I like my rightmost monitor to have the wingpanel on the top and plank on the bottom. When I start up the computer without these commands my wingpanel and plank are on the left most monitor, and if I want to get to my right monitor I need to move my mouse off the left side of the screen to get to the right monitor (like a wrap around)

Comment: Here's the commands for all that: _xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --left-of DVI-0_ , _xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary_ , _sed -i 's/Monitor=.*/Monitor=-1/g' ~/.config/plank/dock1/settings_ , _killall plank_

Comment: Those commands move my monitors into the right positions, sets the correct monitor as the "primary" monitor, forces plank (the dock) onto the correct monitor, and refreshes (kills) plank (the dock)

Comment: It doesn't happen every time I restart. One time I'll restart 5 times in a row and the screen will show mirrored, then the 6th time it'll show correctly. The next 3 times I've had to restart my machine the screens have showed correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Using xrandr, when you specify a monitor position (`--right-of` or `--left-of` etc.), this effectively 'cancels' the mirror.  Therefore, the following cancels the mirroring and places the monitors into a desired position:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --right-of HDMI1
```

This turns the mirror on:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --same-as eDP1
```

To get the names of your built-in and external monitors, to use as arguments in the above commands:

```
xrandr
```

Comment: To list the names of your built-in and external monitors, to put into the xrandr arguments, do `xrandr` without any arguments.